# Is a strictly increasing necessarily a subsequent of an arithmetic progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence such that,
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n - b_{n-1} > 0$$
Is there an arithmetic progression whose subsequent is $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

**Update**
By $\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n - b_{n-1} > 0$, I mean that the limit is not equal to 0, but it is possible that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n - b_{n-1} = +\infty$

Comment: No, take for example $b_n=b_{n-1}+1+\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(b_n)_n$ is a subsequence of an arithmetic progression $(a_n)_n$. Let $d := a_2 - a_1$ be the common difference of the latter. Since $(b_n)_n$ is strictly increasing (by your hypothesis), it follows that $d > 0$. Moreover, $$c_n :=\frac{b_{n + 1} - b_n}{d}$$
is a positive integer for all $n$.

Now, by your hypothesis about the $\lim_n [b_n - b_{n - 1}]$ existing, we see that $(c_n)_n$ converges. However, $c_n$ is integer-valued and thus, must be eventually constant. (**Edit**: Here I've been assuming that the limit is finite.)
In turn, the difference $b_{n + 1} - b_n$ must eventually be constant.

However, we now see that the comment by [dvix](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/291201/dxiv) gives a counterexample. Indeed, taking $$b_{n + 1} = b_n + 1 + \frac{1}{2^n},$$ we see that

- $(b_n)_n$ is strictly increasing,
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - b_{n - 1}) = 1> 0$, but
- $b_{n + 1} - b_n = 1 + 2^{-n}$ is *not* eventually constant.

---

**Edit 2.** Even if $\lim_{n \to \infty}[b_n - b_{n - 1}] = \infty$, it is not necessary that $(b_n)_n$ is a subsequence of an arithmetic sequence.
Consider $b_n = b_{n - 1} + n + 2^{-n}$.

The proof is essentially to show that you cannot find any $d > 0$ such that $$\frac{b_{n + 1} - b_n}{d}$$ is an integer for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks, buy I don't understand why $(c_n)_n$ converge necessarily. For example if $b_n = n^n$, $(c_n)_n$ will grow to $\infty$ and is not constant.

Comment: @Ari.stat: In your post, you are assuming that $b_n - b_{n - 1}$ is convergent. My $c_n$ is just a constant times that sequence and so it must converge. The example you give does not satisfy your own hypothesis.

Comment: Why $b_n - b_{n-1}$ is convergent? If lim $b_n- b_{n-1} > 0$ this also includes the case lim $b_n- b_{n-1}  = +\infty$, right? May be I should have clarified this. All what I meant by $\lim b_n- b_{n-1} > 0$ is that the limit is not equal to 0.

Comment: @Ari.stat: Okay but my answer still works because it shows that whenever $(b_n)_n$ satisfies your hypothesis and $(b_n - b_{n - 1})_n$ converges to a finite value, then it is eventually constant. My counterexample still applies then.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: @Ari.stat: Since you have accepted my answer, I have edited it now to add details for the other case as well, for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

No in general. An increasing arithmetic sequence has its difference between two consecutive terms equal to $r \gt 0$.

And for a general increasing sequence, the difference $b_n -b_{n-1}$ can be strictly positive and converge to zero.

Comment: But I my case $b_n - b_{n-1}$ cannot go to zero because of the condition I set

Comment: I don’t see the condition you refer to. Can you state it precisely.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I think OP is referring to the fact that they've written $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n - b_{n-1} > 0$$ in the question.